# VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount return 0?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` to find child controls, but it always return 0.

Here is my code

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewerChannelsRecordTimeData">
    <StackPanel x:Name="channelsRecordTimeData">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="channelRecordTimeItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="hoursLines">
                        //Some Controls here                            
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C# code:

```
channelRecordTimeItems.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ChannelRecordTimeItemsStatusChangedEventHandler;
private void ChannelRecordTimeItemsStatusChangedEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (channelRecordTimeItems.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        if (channelRecordTimeItems.HasItems)
        {
            DependencyObject dependencyObject = null;
            Grid gridHighlightRecordData = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < channelRecordTimeItems.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                dependencyObject = channelRecordTimeItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i); //dependencyObject != null
                 if (dependencyObject != null)
                 {
                    Grid hoursLines = FindElement.FindChild<Grid>(dependencyObject, "hoursLines"); //hoursLines = null
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
   where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); //Return 0 here
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundChild;
}
```

`VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` always return 0,

The code for constructing for items here

```
List<ChannelRecordTimeItemData> listChannelRecordTimeItemData = new List<ChannelRecordTimeItemData>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ChannelRecordTimeItemData item = new ChannelRecordTimeItemData();
    listChannelRecordTimeItemData.Add(ChannelRecordTimeItemData);
}
channelRecordTimeItems.ItemsSource = listChannelRecordTimeItemData;
channelRecordTimeItems.Items.Refresh();
```

I have searched on forum and internet, but i can not solve it, someone can help me?

Many thanks!

T&T

Comment: Can you explain this binding, ItemsSource="{Binding}" ? I think you should bind your Collection property here.

Comment: Thank you,I have added The code for constructing for items above.

Comment: Are you binding ItemsControl twice, in XAML and code behind ?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked accurately for me. It does find and return Grid hoursLines.

Comment: @Nitesh: Where do you call the function that find Grid hoursLines?
If I call it in a button event click, it worked fine. But if I call it in the StatusChanged event then it not found Grid hoursLines.

Comment: You have to call it after you bind ItemsSource to your ItemsControl.

Comment: I debug and I saw that the Find() Function was called after channelRecordTimeItems.ItemsSource = listChannelRecordTimeItemData;
channelRecordTimeItems.Items.Refresh();
It's right? Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that when the `ItemContainerGenerator` signals the `ContainersGenerated` status, the container (a `ContentPresenter`) has been created, but not yet loaded. Especially the data template has not yet been applied to the ContentPresenter, hence there is nothing in the visual tree.

You may get around this by adding a `Loaded` event handler when looping over the generated containers.

```
private void ItemContainerGeneratorStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.Status
        == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        var containers = itemsControl.Items.Cast<object>().Select(
            item => (FrameworkElement)itemsControl
                .ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));

        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            container.Loaded += ItemContainerLoaded;
        }
    }
}

private void ItemContainerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    element.Loaded -= ItemContainerLoaded;

    var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, 0) as Grid;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your using Caliburn.Micro this will help you.
For your Viewmodel the base Class should be Screen then only VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount() give no.of childs.(because Screen will Activate all childs

or
otherwise (FrameworkElement)YourParent).ApplyTemplate() method