# Iterating through Controls of WPF-Window with nested-hierarchical structure

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have to iterate through all controls of a WPF-Window (I found out how to do that), but the real problem is the nested structure of the controls:
They all are part of grids, stackpanels, TabPages etc... several times.
I want to perform such an iteration because I want to implement kind of an GUI-Linked Settings-System.

My attempt is the following:

```
public List<Control> GetAllControls(DependencyObject dependency)
    {
        List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
        for (int loop = 0; loop < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependency); loop++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependency, loop)) > 0)
                controls.Concat(GetAllControls(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependency, loop)));
            else
                controls.Add((Control)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependency, loop));
        }
        return controls;
    }
```

However, `GetChildrenCount` is always 0, although the given parameter has 7 Items (says IntelliSense).

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because of this line:

```
controls.Concat(GetAllControls(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependency, loop)));
```

`Concat` is a LINQ extension method that will return a new sequence that is a concatenation of two sequences (the original -- `controls` in your case -- and the one supplied to the method). You are not assigning the returned sequence to anything.

What you need is the `AddRange` method of the `List<T>` class. Change the line of code to:

```
controls.AddRange(GetAllControls(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependency, loop)));
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but because `GetChildrenCount()` **always** returns **0**, the content of the for-loop is never being accessed,

Comment: Then maybe this SO question would help you: [VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount return 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894506/visualtreehelper-getchildrencount-return-0)